# How do you interpret these sections of this Security Target?

Tags: translation, interpretation

TSF = Target of evaluation Security Functions

> **FDP_ACF.1.2/JCRMI :**  The TSF shall enforce the following rules to
>   determine if an operation among controlled  subjects and controlled
>   objects is allowed: **none**
>
> **FDP_ACF.1.3/JCRMI :**  The TSF shall explicitly
>   authorise access of subjects to objects based on the following 
>   additional rules: **none**.

Above, you page 64 of security target a *NXP JCOP V2.4.2 R3* smart card. (Its [here](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/ST_Lite_JxE081_v00.02.pdf))

The question is:

What is the meaning of indicating "None" in the end of sentences as the rule?

Does it mean :

For *FDP_ACF.1.2/JCRMI* : TSF could not determine if an operation among controlled 
    subjects and controlled objects is allowed or not?

and for *FDP_ACF.1.3/JCRMI* : The TSF could not authorise access of subjects to objects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how technical specification forms may be laid out/filled in, which has little or no relevance to standard English syntax.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clear what the language issue is. "the following rules...: none" seems clear to me.

Comment: My guess is that there are no additional rules.  But don't ask me - ask the people for whom you are writing the TSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there are no rules enforced in the contexts covered by that subsection.  The antecedent of "none" is "the following rules".  The empty set. { }

Comment: I know, But what is the meaning of no rule?! If there is not any rule, so it is not provided to do it, right?

Comment: What is to be done is not a language question but a programming question, and so it is beyond the scope of this website. You might ask on Stackoverflow or on a forum devoted to the JavaCard.